# How to change a comma for a dot before number of pages in book or thesis in references generated with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm preparing a thesis style for mi University, they have very particular format requirements as usually. In the references lists, they already have their own requirements too. I can solve it almost totally with [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), only remains one thing. The components of the books and thesis must be separated by a period, i can separate all components of the references with exception for the separation between inmediate component before a number of pages (publisher, location, etc.) wich is a comma, and must be a dot. Here is an image with marks in red pointing the cuestion:

[image]

And Here is the code of modification of the author-date BibLaTeX:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,bibencoding=utf8,maxcitenames=2,firstinits=true,natbib=true,doi=false,isbn=false,backend=biber,uniquename=init,maxbibnames=99,dashed=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}} % insert thin spaces between author initials
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} % increase spacing between entries in bibliography
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove 'in:' preceding article title
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, patent, thesis, unpublished]{title}{#1}%no quotes around titles of chapters/article titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, patent, thesis, unpublished,book]{pages}{{\nopp#1}} %removes pp. from pages
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis, book]{pages}{{#1} p} %removes pp. from pages
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{andothers={\it et~al\adddot}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{
\printtext[parens]%
}{%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printtext%
}{}{}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace}     {\addcomma\addspace}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
\printfield{volume}
\setunit*{\addnbthinspace}
  \printfield{number}
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}
  \printfield{eid}
  }
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
\iffieldundef{series}
  {}
{\newunit
 \printfield{series}%
 \setunit{\addspace}}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
\setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\usebibmacro{issue}%
\newunit}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1} %title without ""
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} %title without ""
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1} %journaltitle non-italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{#1} %title non-italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1}
\AtEveryBibitem{
\ifentrytype{misc}{%
 }{%
\clearfield{url}%
\clearfield{urldate}%
}%
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out, I read posts on this site, but so far I could not figure out how to do it, I've tried many things but nothing; I would appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: You will find that `\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, patent, thesis, unpublished,book]{pages}{#1}` should be enough for removing the pages prefix. Plus, you actually seem to abuse the `pages` field, to give the total number of pages for a book or thesis, use the `pagetotal` field. It seems weird to first disable the macro `in:` with `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}` and then to refill it later with `\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}`.

Comment: In your redefinition of `volume+number+eid` you are missing the `%` to suppress end-of-line spaces, same goes for `journal+issuetitle`, though some `%` are present there. In the end you do some `title` formatting again, which partly was done above and partly could have been done in the same line. `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}}` looks like a very dirty hack to me, to insert thin spaces between initials you should use `\newrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addnbthinspace}`.

Comment: Thank you very very much @moewe, i'll try all your suggestions; take in count that my code must be absolutely dirty because i've been adapting the code step by step and problem by problem; now i have to clean the entire code when every thing be perfect.

Comment: Hi @moewe, i begin to clean up my code as you sugests; but your code 
`\newrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addnbthinspace}`
seems not to work, and give this error code:
**! LaTeX Error: Command \bibinitdelim already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.**

Comment: Ah well, it should have been `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\addnbthinspace}` of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX!

The following should do the trick:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

Comment: Please note the difference between `\adddot` and `\addperiod`. The former only adds a dot for abbreviations, while the latter prints a sentence-end period (full stop). If the punctuation mark were directly followed by a bibstring, you would see a difference in capitalisation. Semantically, what you want to print there shouldn't be an abbreviation dot, but a period; and arguably proper capitalisation looks nicer there.

Comment: @moewe: I never paid attention to the difference, but I'll change  the proposed code. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I'm using this solution but in certain places I see "blabla. pp. 4–10.", instead of "blabla. Pp. 4–10.". The incorrect capitalisation seems to be related to what precedes the period (i.e. the "blabla"), but I haven't been able to really pin it down. Two concrete examples: "IEEE. pp. 581–586."  and "27th International Conference on Human Factors in
Computing Systems (April 4-9, 2009, Boston, MA, USA). pp. 78–82.". In the same document I have plenty of other entries where the "Pp." capitalisation is correct. Any ideas @moewe?

Comment: @Matthias Please ask a new question about that. It could have to do with how the punctuation tracker works. If you supply an MWE I will have a look.